# MySql full join (union) and ordering on multiple date columns

Tags: mysql

A rather complicated sql query that I might be making much more difficult that it should be:
I have two tables:

News:
newsid, datetime, newstext

Picture:
pictureid, datetime, imgPath

The two are not related, I am only joining by the date that the news/picture was created on

SQL so far:

```
SELECT * FROM news as n LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(pictureid), datetime 
FROM picture GROUP BY DATE(datetime)) as p ON DATE(n.datetime) = DATE(p.datetime) 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM news as n RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(pictureid), 
datetime FROM picture GROUP BY DATE(datetime)) as p ON 
DATE(n.datetime) = DATE(p.datetime)
```

I have to use union to simulate a full outer join in MySQL.
The results:

```
newsid     text     datetime  count()   datetime 
1       sometext   2011-01-16   1       2011-01-16 
2         moo2    2011-01-19  NULL        NULL 
3        mooo3    2011-01-19  NULL        NULL 
NULL      NULL      NULL       4         2011-01-14
```

The problem being that I obviously end up with two date columns- one from news and one from pictures, this means i cannot order by date and have it be in the correct order! Any ideas? Even if it means restructuring the database! I need date to be in a single column.

The answer came from SeRPRo
The completed working code is:

```
SELECT `newsid`, `text`,
    CASE 
    WHEN `datetime` IS NULL 
    THEN `pdate` 
    ELSE `datetime` 
    END 
    as `datetime`, 

`pcount` FROM 
(
    (SELECT * FROM news as n LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT count(pictureid) as pcount, datetime as pdate FROM picture GROUP BY DATE(datetime)) as p 
        ON DATE(n.datetime) = DATE(p.pdate) ORDER BY datetime
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM news as n RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT count(pictureid) as pcount, datetime as pdate FROM picture GROUP BY DATE(datetime)) as p 
        ON DATE(n.datetime) = DATE(p.pdate) ORDER BY datetime
    ) 

) as x
ORDER BY datetime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just using your database structure and your query, and since FULL OUTER JOIN is not available in MySQL, I think a solution could be this:

```
SELECT
    `newsid`,
    `text`,
    CASE
        WHEN `datetime` IS NULL THEN `pdate`
        ELSE `datetime`
    END as `datetime,
    `pcount`
(
SELECT *
FROM `news` as `n`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT count(pictureid) as `pcount`, datetime as `pdate`
                        FROM picture GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
                    ) as p ON DATE(n.datetime) = DATE(p.datetime) 
    UNION
SELECT * 
    FROM `news` as `n`
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT count(pictureid) as `pcount`, datetime as `pdate`
                        FROM picture GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
                    ) as p ON DATE(n.datetime) = DATE(p.datetime) 

)
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you!
Added the working code to my main post

Answer (score 0):

i think your code would resolved to this finally and could you explain the datetime sort part a bit more in detail

```
SELECT *  
FROM   News FULL OUTER JOIN Picture 
ON News.Datetime = Picture.Datetime ORDER BY DateTime Asc
```

Comment: Yeah that is what is resolves to! Just MySQL doesn't seem to be able to do FULL OUTER JOINs, so the UNION and replication is a work around.

I need the dates to be all in one column to enable me to order them properly- with two columns (one each from picture and news) and the gaps being nulls the query ends up listing all news, then all pictures. Is that any clearer?

Comment: What does the datetime in News represent and datetime in Picture represent. Upload dates? If they are different then you might have to concatenate ex:<pre>select columnA||columnB from TABLEA; (Concats column A and B)</pre>

Comment: Yes, they're just upload dates

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap the query with another:

```
SELECT ..., IF(datetime1 IS NULL, datetime2, datetime1) as datetime, ... FROM
(
   ... your query ...
)
ORDER BY datetime
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing- hadn't thought of that! Thank you!